# count cells which have 10 or more characters when read backwards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet as follows:

```
  Column A
1 +491111961476
2 +9721111965783
```

I'd like to see whether the above cells **have 10 or more characters when read from backwards**. I am using the following formula

```
=countifs(A1:A2;'+49??????????')
```

How do I modify this to suit my need?

Comment: Are you wanting a formula or VBA code?

Comment: I would like a formula

Comment: What do you want the output to be if it does have 10 or more characters?

Comment: i would like those cells to be counted if they can have at least 10 characters when read in reverse. If they have any less, they should be ignored

Comment: so to be correct... in logical (for computers) way, you want to count the cells which start with `"+49"` (germany) and have at least 10 numbers after that... which is 13 numbers in total... am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you are after

`=IF(LEN(A2)>=10,"10 or more","Less than 10")`

Correct forumla usage provided by @DirkReichel

You will need to drag this down for all cells

Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: sorry... but that is just "very" wrong.... `A2>=LEN("10")` should be `LEN(A2)>=10`

Comment: @DirkReichel I dont see how it is "very" wrong, if could explain that would be great

Comment: because `LEN()` will return the length of the given string, which is 2 for `LEN("10")`... you simply flipped over the whole logic, that is all ;)

Comment: Ah, I see, I clearly wasnt thinking too hard when I wrote it, thanks for setting me strait!

Comment: away from the `LEN`-part, there are other reasons your formula is wrong... the whole len of the string would be 13... also, it looks like he wants to check for `+49` at the beginning... that said, your answer doesn't answer the question.... still, it is not 100% clear to me what the requestor wants... maybe something like `=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A1:A2,3)="+49")*(LEN(A1:A2)>=13))`... but I am not sure :/

Comment: @DirkReichel, Well i'll leave it until the OP clarifies but from what you have said you are right, I really shouldnt post answers when im sleepy. It also seems you have hit the nail on the head with you formula